# Create an external link on wordpress site passing the username as a querystring parameter

Tags: wordpress

I am adding a quick link on my wordpress site but that link is a custom link that redirects with the current username thats logged in. So, the link would be something like "http://www.example.com?currentuser={username}". I want this {username} to come from the system but I am not able to find either the right token for it or not sure what I am doing is correct? I am trying to add a quick link -> custom link on my site but needs the current username to be able to pass to as my querystring parameter. How should I go about accomplishing this on the wordpress site?
[image]

Comment: I guess, that won't be possible via adding link via custom links. You will have to create the link dynamically which will render as expected.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? I see I can create a page and maybe add the code in the Text section. All I have access to is an admin login access to the wordpress site. I don't have any backend access as there is a different company that manages the site. With hardly any background on wordpress stuffs, I am trying to figure out the way to do this using the front end as it takes time to hear back from that company.

Comment: So, i installed the insert php on the site and after some digging through, found a way to display the username which it does. Now the problem is I am not able to generate a link on this page. Could you point out what am I missing or doing wrong? Thank you! [insert_php]
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo '<a href="http://www.example.com/Default.aspx?ssouser= ' . $current_user->user_login ." target="_blank">Click here</a>';
[/insert_php]

Comment: Figured out the link and it displays properly on the page. echo '<a href="http://example.com/Default.aspx?ssouser='.$current_user->user_login .'" target="_blank">Click here</a>'; Is there no way to do this on the custom link on the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try if following is useful.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$loggedinuser = $current_user->user_login;
$linkurl = get_site_url().'/?currentuser='.$loggedinuser;
$displaylink = '<a href="'.$linkurl.'">Click Here</a>';
echo($displaylink);
```

Comment: Where should I put this script? I am adding a custom link under Menu, so should this go under the Custom Content section? Sorry new to wordpress, so not sure where I would be putting this code. Thanks!